# translate curl -d "user[email]" data to postman

Tags: curl, ruby-on-rails-5, postman

I have a curl command:

```
curl -i -X POST -d "user[email]"="api_user@domain.com" -d "user[password]"="abcdef" http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in

curl -i -X POST --form "user[email]"="api_user@domain.com" --form "user[password]"="abcdef" http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
```

I'd love to convert the above to postman that can work well with this repo https://github.com/talakoski/rails-devise-jwt However, the auto import doesn't quite work, as tested against hitting the server endpoint. and I do not know how to convert `-d "user[email]"="api_user@domain.com"`, or to a jquery or axios request?

Any help please

Answer (score 1):

To import a CURL command into Postman.

- Click on the import tab.
- Select the Raw Text option and paste your CURL command.
- Hit import and you will have the command in your Postman builder

I have done the same and exported as a [collection](https://files.fm/u/cgv2bxur) for your reference

EDIT

[image]

Comment: I've tried import. i think it's the particular -d "user[email]"="api_user@domain.com" that postman doesn't know how to parse out correctly

Comment: **that postman doesn't know how to parse out correctly** - I don't understand this point, I just tried to import it and it worked fine ( screenshot in the answer section )

Comment: If you clone down this repo and start using postman you will see the discrepancy between raw curl and postman result. https://github.com/talakoski/rails-devise-jwt